# Date and time of an article in a humanized and localized way

Tags: python, datetime, i18n

The goal is displaying the date and time of an article in a humanized and localized way:

> ```
> Yesterday
> 13:21
> ```

or if the Swedish language parameter is set it will display:

> ```
> Igår 
> 13:21
> ```

And if the date wasn't yesterday or today, it will print the date and 24-hour time. I think I succeeded with everything except handling the timezone:

```py
def datetimeformat_jinja(value, format='%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y', locale='en'):
    now= datetime.now()
    info = None
    if datetime.date(value) == datetime.date(now):
      info= _('Today')
    elif (now - value).days < 2:
      info= _('Yesterday')
    else:
      month = value.month
      if month == 1:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Jan')
      elif month == 2:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Feb')
      elif month == 3:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Mar')
      elif month == 4:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('April')
      elif month == 5:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('May')
      elif month == 6:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('June')
      elif month == 7:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('July')
      elif month == 8:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Aug')
      elif month == 9:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Sep')
      elif month == 10:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Oct')
      elif month == 11:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Nov')
      else:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Dec')
    return info+'<br>'+format_time(value, 'H:mm', locale=locale)
```

The above code localizes and humanizes the output:

> ```
> Today
> 3:29
> ```

I can also switch languages to, for example, Portuguese:

> ```
> Hoje
> 3:29
> ```

Where "Hoje" means "today," so the filter appears to work.

Could you please review it or give me a hint on how I can admit my code to also allow time zones? I use babel for localization and Jinja2 for rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Adding time zone support

Add a new argument to your function: `now`. This should be the localized datetime of the client. Compare `now` to the current server datetime and adjust the formatted time by the difference between them. Boom, timezone support added.

That said ***you cannot get the client timezone server-side***. Look into client-side solutions with JavaScript (either full client-side date formatting, or phoning home). [This should start you off on the right track.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2542206/998283)

On with the code review.

### Tidying up the code

#### Variable and function naming

- `info` and `value` are excessively vague.
- `datetimeformat_jinja()` is a bit eccentric  as a function name, as its not in imperative form (eg `format_datetime`).

#### String formatting

Concatenating strings with addition is considered bad practice is Python. You should format individual elements of your message together, rather than starting with `info=''` and adding new parts as you go along. Use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting) (or `%s`-formatting with Python 2.5 and below) to achieve this.

#### The `If`-`elif`-`else` chain

In lines 9 through 33 you copy-pasted the same logic twelve times over; that's a sure-fire sign you need to express things more generically.

#### Style

Take this suggestion for the petty nothing it is, but—please, please, please—unless you're following the style guidelines of your team or employer, read and obey [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

### Result

```
MONTHS = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April', 'May', 'June',
          'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
FORMAT = '%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y'

def format_datetime(to_format, format=FORMAT, locale='en'):
    now = datetime.now()
    if datetime.date(to_format) == datetime.date(now):
        date_str = _('Today')
    elif (now - to_format).days < 2:
        date_str = _('Yesterday')
    else:
        month = MONTHS[to_format.month - 1]
        date_str = '{0} {1}'.format(to_format.day, _(month))
    time_str = format_time(to_format, 'H:mm', locale=locale)
    return "{0}<br>{1}".format(date_str, time_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def datetimeformat_jinja(value, format='%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y', locale='en'):
    now= datetime.now()
```

Put a space after now and before =

```
    info = None
```

Info will always be assigned something later, there is no reason to assign here.

```
    if datetime.date(value) == datetime.date(now):
```

Compare with datetime.date.today(), that'll be a bit clearer.

```
      info= _('Today')
    elif (now - value).days < 2:
```

I'd also use today here.

```
      info= _('Yesterday')
    else:
      month = value.month
      if month == 1:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Jan')
      elif month == 2:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Feb')
      elif month == 3:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Mar')
      elif month == 4:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('April')
      elif month == 5:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('May')
      elif month == 6:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('June')
      elif month == 7:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('July')
      elif month == 8:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Aug')
      elif month == 9:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Sep')
      elif month == 10:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Oct')
      elif month == 11:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Nov')
      else:
        info = str(value.day)+' '+_('Dec')
```

Firstly, no reason to duplicate the code that much. You should have at least put the months in a list and taken advantage of that. But you can get the month name by value.strftime("%b").

Python itself really doesn't have support for time zones. You need a third party library for that. pytz is often used for this purpose.